# add class to div according to where the cursor is

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a class to a div when a button is clicked according to which div last had focus.

i can get the id of the div but not on button click

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="duck">one</div>
<div contenteditable="true" id="dog">two</div>
<div contenteditable="true" id="cat">three</div>
<input type="label" id="showValue"></input>

<button id="clickMe">Click me</button>
```

and the js

```
var divbox = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < divbox.length; i++)
  divbox[i].addEventListener('focus', function() {
    $('#showValue')[0].value = this.id;    
  }, false);


$('#clickMe').click(function() {
 alert(divbox)
});
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/sf9vrj9L/

Comment: Can you explain a little more clearly what it is you are trying to do? When you click on `#clickMe` you want to know which div has (had) focus?

Comment: Side note, there is no input type of label. Also, why are you adding event listeners with plain vanilla JS if you're using jQuery? Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/862xgp3d/) what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm confused... how can you add a class to a div according to where the cursor is as the cursor has to be on the button in order to click it...? (Unless the user uses the keyboard to click the mouse, but that's unlikely unless using accessibility features)

Comment: when I click on the button I want to add a class to the div that had the caret placed in it.  The input is really just there for testing purposes.  
And yes I started off using vanilla js but can use jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still cant understand your purpose, but based in your code you could get it working like this

```js
$(function(){

 $("div").hover(function(){
   $("#showValue").val($(this).attr('id'));
  })

})

$('#clickMe').click(function() {
 $("#"+$("#showValue").val()).addClass('newClass')
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em
}

.newClass {background: pink}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="duck">one</div>
<div contenteditable="true" id="dog">two</div>
<div contenteditable="true" id="cat">three</div>
<input type="text" id="showValue">


<button id="clickMe">
Click me
</button>
```

Comment: the purpose is to target a div based on where the caret is.  At the moment this add the class to where the mouse last was. Although changing it to focus seems to work :)

Answer (score 1):

So, if I'm understanding your problem correctly, one way to tackle it would be like this (also removing the mix of vanilla and jQuery, just use jQuery)

```js
$("div").focusin(function() {
   $(".focused").removeClass("focused");
   $(this).addClass("focused");
});


$('#clickMe').click(function() {
 $(".newClass").removeClass("newClass");
 $(".focused").addClass("newClass");
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em
}

.newClass {background: pink}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="duck">one</div>
<div contenteditable="true" id="dog">two</div>
<div contenteditable="true" id="cat">three</div>


<button id="clickMe">
Click me
</button>
```

The idea is to use the `focusin` event to attach a marker class so you know which div was the last one to have focus. You can't rely on, for example, the `:focus` pseudo class because as soon as you click the button, the div will lose focus. Then when you click the button you just find the div that has the `focused` class and add the `newClass` to it.